# How to grant an access to IPFS file securely using NFT

Tags: blockchain, ipfs, nft

Let's say I want to store and distribute some author's content (text or artwork). As an util for granting access to it I'd like to use NFT for instance. If any user will buy an NFT from specified collection he would have an access to published author's content I mentioned. To achieve fully decentralised content storing I assume to use IPFS. So my question mostly about security: how does the IPFS store files from this point of view? I mean if I try to retrieve any content by CID using their API, I will fetch it as raw data like I uploaded them before. It gives possibility to get author's content with no security policy limiting access to this content.

I suppose it can be handled if I encrypt author's content before uploading to IPFS. But it still doesn't look good because of my service is taking responsibility of protection algorithms. If it goes down somehow, many authors stay with no possibility to fetch their original creations (I mean to get it from IPFS without my service).

So in this case I definitely can implement verification of user's wallet has specific NFT and grant an access (link to IPFS). But is there any way to do it securely and correctly so authors still could get and access to their creations if my service suddenly stopped. Hope I explained my concerns well.

Comment: At the end of the day, encryption or not, if one user gets a copy they can just leak the decrypted version anyways. Also as you're selling something, you're the central "owner" anyways, so I think it's fine for you to be in control of the keys. I think a scheme where there's one key, and multiple certs issued is fine. Transmit key however you like, and generate a unique cert for the purchase, referring to the NFT. That way you can tell who's legit, and who pirated it.

This is more-or-less how Nintendo does it. It's easy to decrypt their content, but only cert owners have a legit copy.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I found a solution. Seems like it the LitProtocol can handle this issue for me. That's not an ad.